# Spring Data Jpa + @Async annotated methods issue

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, asynchronous, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot project which uses spring jpa repositories to access the database. I have a one to many relationship (one AccountRequest, many States, AccountRequest has a List of States field), and very often I add new States to that list.

When I save an accountRequest, all the new states in the list get persisted.

Now, I need to save some states inside a @Async annotated method, but when I do that, e.g:

```
@Async()
public void businessMethod(AccountRequest request) {
   saveState(request, "Consulting government policies");
   saveState(request, "Enforcing rules");
   saveState(request, "Process ended successfully");
}

public void saveState(AccountRequest request, String stateDescription) {
   // do stuff
   request.addState(new State(stateDescription));
   // do stuff
   requestRepository.save(request);
}
```

I get the next behavior, when line 1 in businessMethod has run:

- State "Consulting government policies" gets persisted

When line 2 in businessMethod has run:

- State "Consulting government policies" gets persisted again
- State "Enforcing rules" gets persisted

And when line 3 in businessMethod has run:

- State "Consulting government policies" gets persisted again
- State "Enforcing rules" gets persisted again
- State "Process ended successfully" gets persisted

And I end up with these six states:

- Consulting government policies
- Consulting government policies
- Enforcing rules
- Consulting government policies
- Enforcing rules
- Process ended successfully

Instead of the intended three:

- Consulting government policies
- Enforcing rules
- Process ended successfully

Does anyone know why? Any suggestion of what to read to understand what is happening here?

Answer (score 3):

Well you are saving the same `AccountRequest request` three times and simply adding objects to the list with `request.addState(new State(stateDescription));` , so hibernate saves it as it should i could say.

In detail :

```
1st saveState() : 
        adding "Consulting government policies" 
        saving request with the list -> list.size()=1
2nd saveState() : 
        adding "Enforcing rules"
        saving request with the list -> list.size()=2
3d  saveState() : 
        adding "Process ended successfully"
        saving request with the list -> list.size()=3
```

Also note that if you haven't configured a proper `Executor` or you have placed `@Async` above a method which getting called inside the same class, it wont get wrapped properly, so it wont run asynchronously.
Now in case that you faced different behavior while calling the same method without `@Async`, then you might have a problem with your transaction manager or the persistence unit so it flushes the session immediately causing 3 sequential *new* inserts to the database. In case that the session does not flush/commit transaction immediately, it causes 3 merges -> 1 final insert with the full list.

Some site-links just for reference.

[Spring Async Example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/)
[Hibernate Cascade](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-cascade)
[Entity Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqw.html)

Comment: Thanks, as you said at the end, it is probably a problem with the entity manager, as I only get this behavior when using @Async

Comment: well if you could double check your spring logs with debug on, in order to see whats going on while executing the queries. At least you could verify that `businessMethod()` is getting wrapped in one transaction and doesnt commit three. Also as we dont know the rest of your 'project' i suppose that after calling the `@Async` method , you are not  modifying the `AccountRequest request` instance !?!?